# dotVVM passing values from databinded DOM-elements to javascript vars for visualisation

Tags: javascript, c#, knockout.js, data-binding, dotvvm

I am creating a dotVVM webApp for data-visualisation but get a little problem:

Because of the data-binding between my view(html) and my viewModel(c#) i only get knockout comment strings back by those DOM-elements. 
(dotVVM is using Knockout.js for data-binding)

The var currency gets following value : "<"!-- ko text: Currency --">"<"!-- /ko --">" and is displayed in my input field with id of "1".

I need to get the right value (in this case 40 or initial value 400) into javascript-var for visualisation.

```js
        var currency = document.getElementById("textBox").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("1").value= currency;
```

```html
 <div ID="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>

    <p ID="textBox">{{value: Currency}}</p>
    <input ID="1" value="" style="width: 900px" /
```

And this is my ViewModel (just as simple as it can be for demonstration purpose)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the active page. This is used in the top menu bar to 
    highlight the current menu item.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string ActivePage => Context.Route.RouteName;

    public int Currency { get; set; } = 400;

    public void currency()
    {                    
            Currency = 40;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can probably use `<dot:TextBox Text="{value: Currency}" />` to get a `<input type="text">` bound to `Currency` property.

If you can't use this and don't want to write your own control, you can access data context as you would in knockout.js - `<input type="text" data-bind="value: Currency" />` is the same as the `TextBox` and you can use `ko.dataFor(element)` to access view model for the element or `ko.contextFor(element)` to access knockout context with $parent, $index, ....

This is how you can get currency in Javascript:

`var currency = knockout.dataFor(document.getElementById("textBox")).Currency();`